# Converting Tex to image

Tags: image, latex

I'm trying to convert Tex stuff (tabulars and the like) to images (e.g. PNGs) using the following commands:

```
texi2dvi foobar.tex
dvips -E foobar.dvi
convert -density 300 foobar.ps foobar.png
```

This gives me a PS file which is then converted to PNG. The important thing is that the size of the resulting image should be just big enough for the tabular, and not as big as an entire page. This works so far, but the image quality is not really convincing.

Does anybody know of an alternative solution?

Comment: You may find this question on [tex.se] helpful: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11866/86

Comment: Indeed, thanks a lot! If you provide this as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: As requested (and it's taken me longer to write this comment than the answer due to that wretched 15 character limit (which seems not to include the `@jena: ` bit, and the 15 second delay between posting comments!)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an answer to this on the [TeX-SX](http://tex.stackexchange.com) sister site at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11866/86.  I recommend looking at that question, its answers, and the related links.